# Counting past occurrence given a classification

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a Table just like the one in the picture below. I want to count the number of cells in the column Leg since the last entry, given a certain classification on the column Type.
For example, for the type KFT only, how many blank entries are there in the column Legendary since the last entry for Leg?

I know how to solve this issue creating helper columns. But given that I have too many types, I would have to create a helper column for each type, making my table too big given the amount of rows I have. Is there any way I can create a VBA function to perform this task for me, such that I only need one cell per type to let me know the amount of blank cells since last Leg entry for each type? Here is a short example of how my table looks, using only 2 types:

[image]

In this example, I need a formula with output 0 for MSG, since it has been 0 entries since the last Leg for MSG, and output 2 for UNG, since it has been 2 entries since the last Leg for UNG.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: ... so you never even bothered trying countif(s)?

Comment: If you already have the problem solved with helper columns, can you post your solution with helper columns so we know what you want the output to be? Your question is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

***Using single scary formula***

Alright then. I think best solution to your problem is using helper column or VBA but if you really want to use just one formula, I've something for you. This formula is *very very scary* and someone might give you better solution also, but this formula does work.

In the below formula I've assumed data to be in range `A2:F100`. Change `100` to you number of rows of data. (change all 100's, best way will be to copy formula without `=` in an empty sheet and then `FIND` `100` and `REPLACE ALL` to your row number)

If you have listed `Types` in `Column H` starting from `Cell H2` then in `Cell I2` enter the following formul, drag/copy down as required.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("F" & INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=1),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1 & ":F" & IF(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=1),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1>INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=""),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1,100,INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=""),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1)),"",INDIRECT("B" & INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=1),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1 & ":B" & IF(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=1),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1>INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=""),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1,100,INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$100=H2)*($F$2:$F$100=""),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,1,1))+1)))+1)),H2)
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

---

#### Solution 2

***Using Helper Columns***

Assuming you listed all `Types` in `Column H` starting from `Cell H2` then in `Cell I2` enter the following **array formula** to get the last row from data for corresponding `Type` in `Column H` and `Leg =1`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$11=H2)*($F$2:$F$11=1),ROW($B$2:$B$11)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,1,1))+1)))+1
```

Then in `Cell J2`, enter the below **array formula** to get the last row from data for corresponding `Type` in `Column H` and `Leg ="" (blank)`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$11=H2)*($F$2:$F$11=""),ROW($B$2:$B$11)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,1,1))+1)))+1
```

Next, in `Cell K2`, enter the below formula to set last row if there's no row corresponding to particular type for which leg is blank (for example in my sample data `ABC` do not have empty `Leg`)

```
=IF(I2>J2,11,J2)
```

Finally, in `Cell E2` enter the following formula to get `Count`

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("F" & I2 & ":F" & K2),"",INDIRECT("B" & I2 & ":B" & K2),H2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! It works perfectly. To others thinking of using this formula: you must not only change the references, but change the INDIRECT references for row numbers and column names as well. Thanks so much!